# FirebaseAuth: [Reload] RemoteException when sending get token

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I updated my Firebase from (FirebaseAuth) 16.2.1 to Firebase 18.0.0 and now during the user registration (which was working on FB 16.2.1), calling for example:

`mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener....`

my app enters in a loop with the following error in the Logcat:

```
E/FirebaseAuth: [Reload] RemoteException when sending get token and account info user response
        android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1147)
  android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1147)
        at cux.c(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):1)
        at bqvf.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):7)
        at bqvb.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):5)
        at bqup.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):3)
        at bqru.a(:com.google.android.gms@xx9@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):163)
        at bqum.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):6)
        at bqtg.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):41)
        at bqsm.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):2)
        at bqrz.a(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):8)
        at sfn.run(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):28)
        at bkng.run(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):2)
        at skq.b(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):37)
        at skq.run(:com.google.android.gms@x@17.7.85 (100408-253824076):18)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at sqo.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

My gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

Checklist:

- Migrated to AndroidX
- android.useAndroidX=true & android.enableJetifier=true in my Gradle.properties
- SHA1 & SHA256 Code in my Firebase
- Google Play Services up to date

The funny thing is, somethimes it works, but in 80% of the cases, the app enters in the loophole. Forcing to stop the google play services stops the loop.

I just don't understand what's the problem here! Can you help me?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error with Anonymous user.

Comment: Try to empty the cache of Google Play Service, this should fix it